# Automatic resolution of merge conflicts on GitHub pull request page

Tags: github, merge-conflict-resolution, merge-strategy

I have a GitHub repo with (among others) `hashes.txt` file. Often, when working on feature branch, I have merge conflicts in `hashes.txt` when creating Pull Request to master branch. What i want to achieve is to ignore those merge conflict for this specific file **only**, and always accept version that comes with feature branch. Is it possible to configure GitHub pull request in such a way? I've been reading alot on this subject, action that I am looking for is copy-merge, can be achieved with merge driver set to accept=theirs and all that stuff. It's pretty well documented how to achieve that on my local repo with generic git commands, ie here:

https://gist.github.com/z-vr/b70bef80b955e83d44c0b685e4f40bfe

But the question is how to achieve that on github server? I really can't find any info on that. Especially specifying merge driver in .git/config file, which by default is local, and I can't commit and push those changes to github:

```
[merge "ours"]
    driver = true
```

Here's example screenshot of notification that i never want to see :)
[image]

filename is different as those are just my work-in-progress tests, but ideally this conflict message never appears and github handles that merege automatically.

Any input is much appreciated!